# Sending e-mail in a loop with debug mode turned on, only displays one message

Tags: cakephp

Testing out the Email component in CakePHP 1.3.8 and was wondering if the behavior that I'm witnessing is normal.

I'm attempting to send multiple emails in a loop with the `delivery` property set to `debug`.  After the `send` I do make a call to the `reset()` method but in the debug display of the message(s) sent, only 1 debug e-mail message is displayed.

Here's the code.

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
    $this->Email->from = 'noreply@domain.com';
    $this->Email->subject = "Subject goes here";
    $this->Email->to = $email['recipient'];
    $this->Email->send( $email['message'].' '.$email['url'] );
    $this->Email->reset();
}
```

Anyone else experiencing this particular issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a flash message, so only the last one stored in the session. It is normal it is designed to work so. If you need all store each email flash in a variable and after the loop push it back.